# ¿Diferentes tipos de datos en un mismo Array?

Tags: android, kotlin

Es posible tener màs de un tipo de dato en un arrayOf,un ListOf o un arrayListOf
¿O no es posible tener datos de tipo Int y String, por ejemplo, en un mismo Array?

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible podrias crear un List de Any y lo instanciarias de la siguiente manera:

```
val myList = mutableListOf<Any>()
```

Y le agregarias objetos de la siguiente manera.

```
myList.add("string")
myList.add(MyObject(null, null))
```

Intentalo, y me avisas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede, debes usar arrayOf() para generar un arreglo con valores mixtos :)

```
val myArray = arrayOf(4, 5, 7, "3", "Chike", false).
```

Doc. https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/kotlin-from-scratch-variables-basic-types-arrays-type-inference-and-comments--cms-29328

Comment: por qué cuando trato de imprimirlo me sale:[Ljava.lang.Object;@2f0e140b